# How do I access text files from my computer?

Tags: list, file, python-3.x, text

My current code is as follows but I cannot figure out how to access a text file (e.g "john.txt")

```
    def read_script():
        while True:
            try:
                filename = input('Please Enter Text Name: ')
                F = open (filename, 'r')
                script - F.read()
                F.close()
                slist = script.split()
                return slist
            except OSError:
                print ('Oops! That file does not exist! Try spelling it correctly: ')

    def pig_english():
        letterlist = [i + i[0] for i in read_script()]
        ayList = [i + 'ay' for i in letterlist]
        delaylist = [i[1:] for i in aylist]
        print (delaylist)


    read_script()
    pig_english()
```

Comment: Problem detected: `script - F.read()`

Comment: oops but even when I put script = F.read() I get an error prompt. Hmmm

Comment: What kind of error prompt?

Comment: even when I input a proper text file, it still brings me to the "oops! That file does not exist" part

Comment: I don't know if this is your _only_ problem, but I'm pretty sure you don't need that `read_script()` call before `pig_english()`, since `pig_english` calls `read_script` itself.

Comment: that makes sense. Still not sure how to make my program recognize a text file.

Comment: The file you're trying to open, is it in the same directory as your Python file? Also, how are you running the script? From the command line? Using an IDE such as IDLE or Eclipse?

Comment: Yes. It is in the same directory and I am using IDLE

Comment: Hmm, I wonder if IDLE is affecting the current working directory somehow...

Answer (score 0):

you want raw_input() and not input(). input() interprets the user input as an object and not a string.

Comment: Depends on the version. If OP is using 2.7, I agree with you. But in 3.X, `input` returns a string.

Comment: Yes, I am using 3.X so my input is automatically a string.